# How to get the height of image inside Bootstrap modal dialog (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

This is sorta driving me insane, I have this modal that is scrolling past the window view, but I need to know the height of its content.

Now, my JS gives that their height is 0, so naturally I went and console.log the node object to inspect what's wrong.

And then... in the browser console, it gives the actual height it should be, but... not if I console.log directly the height attribute.

So, how can I get the actual height of a div and what is going on here?

Code:

```js
$('.modal').modal('toggle');

for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  $('.modal-body').append(`
   <img src="https://i.imgur.com/FcOwQDX.gif">
  `)
}

for (const img of $('.modal-body').children()) {
  console.log(img, img.offsetHeight);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because you aren't waiting for them to be loaded before checking

Comment: @PatrickEvans Oh duh, makes sense now, but I'm not sure how to approach the solution, in my example I used the same image but in reality each will be an unique image, should I first convert them to a base64 so its pre-loaded? I'm not sure

Comment: Do it in the image's `onload` event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The `onload` event

You should check the `offsetHeight` of the image, when the `onLoad` event is triggered.

Example :

```js
let img = $('<img src="https://i.imgur.com/FcOwQDX.gif">');
img.on('load', function(){
  alert( 'offsetHeight : ' +  this.offsetHeight+ 'px' )
});
$('.container').append(img)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"> </div>
```

### Bootstrap `modal dialog`

However, you are using a *Bootstrap* `modal dialog`, wich adjusts automatically its size according to the contents, using an animation.
In consequence,  until the `modal dialog` finishes the animation, you will not be able to get the real image Height.

You should wait for the `shown.bs.modal` [event](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events).

> This event is fired when the modal has been made visible to the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

Usage :

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log('modal box resizing complete. Content sizes ready to be checked!')
})
```